# Setup for Streamlit in Docker Compose Environment (React, Nginx, Django) not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, streamlit

Hey I am trying to build a root for a personal portfolio. All containers are running except Streamlit. Streamlit should be accessible via mydomain.com/streamlit. Locally everything works without problems. After calling the homepage and running containers I get a white screen.

Streamlit Config:

```toml
[server]
headless=true
port=8501
enableCORS=false
enableXsrfProtection=false
enableWebsocketCompression=false
[browser]
serverAddress="0.0.0.0"
serverPort=8501
```

NGINX Config :

```
server {
    
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.de;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;



    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.de;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/ss-bundle.key;
    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /streamlit {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        proxy_pass http://streamlit:8501;
    }


    location /api {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8000;
    }

    location /django_static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/django_static/;
    }
}
```

The Docker-Compose file:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
    nginx: 
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/django_static
            - ./docker/nginx/production:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./docker/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
        depends_on:
            - backend
        environment:
            - COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200
    backend:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
        entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/wsgi-entrypoint.sh
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/django_static
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200
        expose:
            - 8000        
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:13.0-alpine
        volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
        - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django
        - DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
        - DB_HOST=db
        - DB_PORT=5432
        - DEBUG=1

    redis:
        image: redis:6.2
        command: redis-server
        ports:
        - 6379:6379
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200


    streamlit:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/streamlit/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 8501:8501
        environment:
            - COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200
        entrypoint: /app/docker/streamlit/entrypoint.sh


volumes:
    static_volume: {}
    postgres_data:
```

And the Dockerfile for Streamlit:

```sh
# docker/streamlit/Dockerfile

FROM python:3.10.5

WORKDIR /app
ADD ./streamlit/portfolio-streamlit-wrapper/requirements.txt /app/streamlit/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r streamlit/requirements.txt

ADD ./docker /app/docker
ADD ./streamlit/portfolio-streamlit-wrapper/ /app/streamlit 

EXPOSE 8501

RUN chmod +x /app/docker/streamlit/entrypoint.sh
```

The whole project builds up normally. I have access to the Django Admin Dashboard and all containers are running. The regular home page is also displayed. Does anyone have any idea what the reason could be that the homepage changes the HTML - title but the streamlit dashboard is not visible?

Edit:
Streamlit is started due an entryscript: Which I cant explain why I created it.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

until cd /app/streamlit/
do
    echo "Waiting for server volume..."
done 

streamlit run welcome.py
```

Answer (score 0):

#If anyone is still facing similar issue try this.

```
location /streamlit {
    rewrite ^/streamlit/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    proxy_pass http://streamlit:8501;
}
```